# Write a program that reads in a pixel value (a 24-bit number that defines RGB colour values), and updates the pixel value based on the second input

Tags: python-3.x

Hexadecimal colours

Write a program that reads in a pixel value (a 24-bit number that defines RGB colour values), and updates the pixel value based on the second input, which will either be:

separate RGB channel values (base 10 integers), or another pixel value.

Each RGB channel in the pixel should be independent of the others. If an update causes overflow or underflow in one channel, the other channels should be unaffected by this. The new pixel value should still be a 24-bit number.

The program I write is almost correct but cannot work when an update causes overflow or underflow in one channel.

```
z_pixelv= input('Please provide a pixel value: ')
z_pixelv = int(z_pixelv,16)
channelv_or_pv = input('Please provide channel values or pixel value: ')
red = (z_pixelv & 0xFF0000)>>16
green = (z_pixelv & 0x00FF00)>>8
blue =(z_pixelv & 0x0000FF)>>0
if channelv_or_pv[1]=='x':
    hexvalue = int(channelv_or_pv,16)
else:
    k = [int(i) for i in channelv_or_pv.split()]
    hexvalue=((k[0] << 16)+(k[1]<<8)+k[2]<<0)
j = z_pixelv + hexvalue
print('Your new pixel value is: {}'.format(hex(j)))
```

Expected result 1(overflow):

```
Please provide a pixel value: 0xFFFFFF
Please provide channel values or pixel value: 10 10 10
Your new pixel value is: 0x090909
```

Actual result 1(overflow):

```
Please provide a pixel value: 0xFFFFFF
Please provide channel values or pixel value: 10 10 10
Your new pixel value is: 0x10a0a09
```

Expected result 2(underflow):

```
Please provide a pixel value: 0x505050
Please provide channel values or pixel value: -90 -80 -80
Your new pixel value is: 0xf60000
```

Actual result 2(underflow):

```
Please provide a pixel value: 0x505050
Please provide channel values or pixel value: -90 -80 -80
Your new pixel value is: -0xa0000
```

actual/expected result 3(correct):

```
Please provide a pixel value: 0x505050
Please provide channel values or pixel value: 0x005000
Your new pixel value is: 0x50a050
```

actual/expected result 4(correct):

```
Please provide a pixel value: 0x505050
Please provide channel values or pixel value: 50 00 00
Your new pixel value is: 0x825050
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be works.

```
pixel_value = input("Please provide a pixel value: ")
channel_or_pixel_value = input("Please provide channel values or pixel value: ")
pixel_value = pixel_value[2:]
value = int(pixel_value, 16)
red1 = (value & 0xFF0000) >> 16
green1 = (value & 0x00FF00) >> 8
blue1 = (value & 0x0000FF) >> 0
if channel_or_pixel_value[1] == 'x':
    pixel_value = channel_or_pixel_value[2:]
    pixel_value = int(pixel_value, 16)
    pixel_red = (pixel_value & 0xFF0000) >> 16
    pixel_green = (pixel_value & 0x00FF00) >> 8
    pixel_blue = (pixel_value & 0x0000FF) >> 0
if channel_or_pixel_value[1] == 'x':
    red2 = red1 + int(pixel_red)
    green2 = green1 + int(pixel_green)
    blue2 = blue1 + int(pixel_blue)
else:
    channel_value = channel_or_pixel_value.split()
    red2 = red1 + int(channel_value[0])
    green2 = green1 + int(channel_value[1])
    blue2 = blue1 + int(channel_value[2])
    if red2 < 0:
        red2 += 256
    if green2 < 0:
        green2 += 256
    if blue2 < 0:
        blue2 += 256
    if red2 > 256:
        red2 -= 256
    if green2 > 256:
        green2 -= 256
    if blue2 > 256:
        blue2 -= 256
print("Your new pixel value is: 0x{0:02x}{1:02x}{2:02x}".format(red2, green2, blue2))
```